# Get Nodes from xml by specifying limit

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, xml-parsing, elementtree

Here is the `xml` ,

```
<Faculty>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>A</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>C</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>E</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>G</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>H</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>

</Faculty>
```

I want to get `nodes` from this `xml` by providing `index` ,

For e.g. If i provide `3` to `6` the output should be like ,

```
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>C</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>E</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
```

How to do this using `etree python` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find all `facultyMember` items and use python's list slicing:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


data = """<Faculty>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>A</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>C</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>E</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>G</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
    <facultyMember>
        <FirstName>H</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>

</Faculty>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
begin, end = 3, 6

for element in tree.findall('.//facultyMember')[begin - 1: end]:
    print ET.tostring(element).strip()
```

prints:

```
<facultyMember>
        <FirstName>C</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
<facultyMember>
        <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
<facultyMember>
        <FirstName>E</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
<facultyMember>
        <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    </facultyMember>
```

Comment: Thanks , But what if i want to in the format like `OrderedDict` in `list` ?

Comment: Ok, could you provide the desired output? Thanks.